# mySQL BULK INSERT from CSV file

Tags: mysql, shell

Can someone assist with the following?
It is giving me a `>` on a linux command line

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -hhostnamet databasename -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'https://www.testza.co.za/domain.csv' INTO TABLE leads FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES"
```

Comment: The character `>` probably means that one quote is not closed. Try to see if a " or ' is missing.

Comment: I have doubts that you can use an URL as the source file for LOAD DATA INFILE. I have never seen that used. As far as I know, you must give the path to a file on the database server, not a remote file.

Answer (score 1):

The `>` on the command line just asks for more input, because there are open quotes in your command.

Just escape all your `"` and `'` by `\"` or `\'` and you should be fine. 
Do the same with `\r\n` (-> `\\r\\n`).

Comment: mysql -uusername -ppassword -hhostname database_db -e  "LOAD DATA INFILE 'exportsmannual/csvfile.csv' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES"

Comment: the above is now returning error 

ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'leadsdata_usr'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: Well, what do you think has happened, when it says "Access denied"? Either your password is wrong or your username. Check both. Here you won't find an answer for the correct one.

Comment: So the solution is I ended up using the following:

mysqlimport -uusername -ppassword -hhostname databasename --columns=applicationdate,firstname,lastname,idnumber,loanrequired,salary,mobilenumber,emailaddress,province,loandeclined,reason  --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by="," --lines-terminated-by="\n" --local exportsmanual/filename.csv

It worked like a charm. I think LOAD DATA INFILE only works within PHPMYADMIN or when you are logged into mysql and not as a direct command on the linux shell prompt or as a bash script